# Import from .sql file to cassandra table

Tags: import, cql, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

I am new to Cassandra database, I have created keyspace and table.Then,
I would like to execute large number of queries that are saved inside a test.sql file ( I dont want to perform Importing from CSV ). My test.sql file content is looks like this..

```
INSERT INTO contact_detail (<fields>) VALUES(<values>);
INSERT INTO contact_detail (<fields>) VALUES(<values>);
INSERT INTO contact_detail (<fields>) VALUES(<values>);
INSERT INTO contact_detail (<fields>) VALUES(<values>);
```

I have saved this file into Cassandra bin directory.

how can i run this file and execute all the insert statement? I need to insert all the values to Cassandra Database, how is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Save the file on the one of the nodes. Then run `cqlsh -f <file name> -k <keyspace name>` on that node.

For more info check here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SOURCE](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/source_r.html) command from inside cqlsh to run any CQL script (file path is relative from you launched the cqlsh command).